# Python: Why does calling just "f" run >4x faster than "f()"?

Tags: python

I just saw Alex Martelli demonstrate this tonight. I didn't catch his explanation for why there's such a large discrepancy in speed here, and I'm still really curious:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'def f(): pass' 'f()'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.121 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'def f(): pass' 'f'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0265 usec per loop
```

So why does `f` run so much faster than `f()`? Admittedly, the example's a bit contrived because I don't know if it generalizes to all possible functions that take no arguments. What's going on under the hood here?

Comment: Because you have no idea what you are doing. The first line execute the f() method. That's why () is used. The second line is doing nothing. Strange question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` doesn't do anything. It doesn't call `f`. You might as well have

```
def f(): pass

"foo"
```

To further elaborate, here's the output when run in interactive mode:

```
>>> def f(): print("Foo!")
... 
>>> f()
Foo!
>>> f
<function f at 0x10ebe9830>
>>>
```

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. I'll actually run the code next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you just enter `f` it just calls on the object and does not do anything and when you call `f()` it actually executes the function

You will notice a difference when you type it into an interpreter:

```
def f():
    print "foo"
f
>>> <function f at 0x02D64670>

f()
>>> foo
```